# How to determine where the data is not linear anymore

Tags: hypothesis-testing, linear-regression

I have some data. When I plot these data, the graph looks very linear when $x>x_0$ (In the following figure $x_0$ is shown by dashed lines). One way to determine the exact location where the graph is linear is to use eyeball, but that is very subjective and does not see scientific.

[image]

The question are (1) what is the criterion for determining $x_0$?  (2) how can we implement the criterion using say MATLAB or Python?

Comment: How many data points are in this graph? And are you assured that there is some data point after which all the points are very linear?

Comment: You can plot the fitting residual (reduced $\chi^2$) with respect to the cutoff $x_0$. If you have true uncertainties for your measurements, you can then see where reduced $\chi^2$ goes over a certain limit. If you don't have uncertainties (standard deviations), the threshold will again be subjective.

Comment: "Very" is by its nature subjective. To get an objective criterion, you need to be more precise about what you want.  For example, you might choose some $\epsilon > 0$ and ask for the least $x_0$ such that there exist $a$ and $b$ with $|y - (a x + b)| \le \epsilon$ for $x \ge x_0$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister    I have about 100 (x,y) pairs. The data look like this above figure.

Comment: @RobertIsrael. The question is how to determine $\epsilon$. I am looking for something like 95% or 99% certainty.

Comment: What do you mean by "$95%$ or $99%$ certainty"?  There is no probability model here, at least none that you have mentioned.  $\epsilon$ is whatever you want it to be.